Convert links to be shown in a modal
I am trying to alter links in my footer to be opened in a modal:
function mymodule_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  $items = &$variables['items'];
  $attributes = [
    'class' => 'use-ajax',
    'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
    'data-dialog-options' => json_encode([
      'height' => 'auto',
      'maxHeight' => false,
      'width' => 'auto',
      'classes' => [
        'ui-dialog' => 'footer-modal'
      ]
    ]),
  ];

  foreach ($items as &$item) {
    $item_attributes = $item['url']->getOption('attributes') ?: [];
    if (!isset($item_attributes['class'])) {
      $item_attributes['class'] = [];
    }
    $item_attributes['class'] = !is_array($item_attributes['class']) ? explode(' ', $item_attributes['class']) : $item_attributes['class'];

    $item['url']->setOption('attributes', array_merge($item_attributes, $attributes));
  }
} 

The footer links seem to be altered correctly, they have the class 'use-ajax' as well as the data-dialog-type="modal" attribute. However these menu links still are not opened in a modal, but as regular links.
The output looks like this.
<a href="/node/41" class="nav-link use-ajax nav-link--node-41" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;height&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;classes&quot;:{&quot;ui-dialog&quot;:&quot;footer-modal&quot;}}" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/41" data-once="ajax">About us</a>


Did you try to add 'target' => '_blank' in your attributes ?

If I add this, just tried, then the links open in a new tab,  but not a modal.

You have to attach this library:
function mymodule_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
  ...
}

Otherwise the code is OK, I've pasted it in a project of mine and all menu links are modal now.
If it is not working, check the HTML source in the browser. This is the minimal version necessary to open a modal:
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/contact">Open form</a>

You can put it in a template to check if the modal library is loading correctly. When the js library has been attached it looks like this:
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/contact" data-once="ajax">Open form</a>

and you should see a click event added in the Event-Listeners tab of the F12 tools for this element.

This library is already loaded. I also included it again, but still the links don't open in a moda.

OK, this was the most obvious thing missing in your code and others who find your post might have exactly this problem. And there is no harm in declaring a dependency twice, the other reference might go away someday in the future.

I declared the dependency twice to be sure it's included. I have inlcuded a modal link manually in the content area of the page and the modal works. The library is loaded.
I updated my question including the html source. It looks correct and like yours.

Yes, this looks OK and the js library is attached when you have data-once="ajax". The next step would be to debug the mouse click client-side, which produces an Ajax request/response pair you see in the F12 tools. Ajax responses have to be 100 % JSON, if there is a problem with the format this is often non-JSON debug output.

I don't know how to do this. I had a look at the click event in the event listeners tab but I don't know what to look for. In the meantime I also changed the theme to olivero, but the result is the same.

F12 - Network Tab - Filter Button "Fetch/XHR". Then click the link. You can try both, the manual and the menu link, and see what is different.

For the manual link that works it shows the path with _wrapper_format=drupal_modal . But for the menu items it opens the new page and it only shows statistics.php.

And what happens if you install mymodule with this one hook on a fresh Drupal site?

Same result, it's the same.

Thank you. I found the issue using a clena new menu. It was due to the hierarchical structure and using  for the first item. My code also added the use-ajax class to this  item. I don't know exactly why, but when removing it from these items, all other items work correctly.
